# Laravel livewire wire:model is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

The data is being sent from the livewire component to the livewire blade file but when I try to apply the wire:model then it isn't sending the ajax request from the livewire blade to the livewire component.

index.blade.php

```
<div class="card-header p-4 min-h-unset" id="kt_contacts_list_header">
    <!--begin::Form-->
    <p> Name: {{$name}}</p> <!--it is printing the name coming from the livewire component-->
    <form class="d-flex align-items-center position-relative w-100 m-0" autocomplete="off">
        <!--begin::Icon-->
        <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: icons/duotune/general/gen021.svg-->
        <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-3 svg-icon-gray-500 position-absolute top-50 ms-5 translate-middle-y">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
                        <rect opacity="0.5" x="17.0365" y="15.1223" width="8.15546" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(45 17.0365 15.1223)" fill="black" />
                        <path d="M11 19C6.55556 19 3 15.4444 3 11C3 6.55556 6.55556 3 11 3C15.4444 3 19 6.55556 19 11C19 15.4444 15.4444 19 11 19ZM11 5C7.53333 5 5 7.53333 5 11C5 14.4667 7.53333 17 11 17C14.4667 17 17 14.4667 17 11C17 7.53333 14.4667 5 11 5Z" fill="black" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
        <!--end::Svg Icon-->
        <!--end::Icon-->
        <!--begin::Input-->
        <!--Livewire model-->
        <input wire:model="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid ps-13" name="search" value="" placeholder="{{__('Search contacts')}}" />
        <!--end::Input-->
    </form>
    <!--end::Form-->
</div>
```

index.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Tenant\Modules\Contacts;

use Livewire\Component;

class Index extends Component
{
    public $group;
    public $name;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->name = 'Zain';
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tenant.modules.contacts.index');
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: dd($name), does it return something?, like you can add a button <button wire:click="show_name">click</button>. Go to livewire and add the function public function show_name(){dd($this->name)}.  When you remove the $this->name from the mount what does it return in the view?

Comment: I see that you don't use a Method on your form, like POST,GET.. So it may be the reason. try adding <form class="d-flex align-items-center position-relative w-100 m-0" autocomplete="off"  wire:submit.prevent="your_action_function()">, with wire:submit.prevent="", is going to call a function and do all the functionality, to test this you colud add the function I told you early(show_name)-> wire:submit.prevent="show_name()"

Comment: @haruk1515 Thank you so much for commenting. I have got the solution. When I removed the `@section` it started working.

Comment: Glad to hear that, Keep the good work going!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Appreciated

Comment: Maybe you can answer your question with the answer for future people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. When I removed the `@section` directive from the livewire blade it started working.

Comment: You've saved my day!

Comment: You saved the day but how will the blade be rendered by the layouts/app.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

In my case `wire:model` wasn't working because the Livewire page component had another root element:

```html
<style>
    /* ... */
</style>

<div>
    <input wire:model="message">
    [...]
</div>
```

It didn't throw an error but once I moved the `<style>` tag inside the main `<div>`, it worked.